# integration of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{n}(t)dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}(t)dt =?$$
To solve this problem, I was thinking that I would let $\cos(t)= \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}$, then the integral will have the form: 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left (\frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2} \right)^{n}dt=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\,\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i(n-2k)t}\,dt$$

From this point, I was stuck. So, would anyone please help me to walk through this problem.

Comment: consider integration by parts and induction

Comment: See [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals). The article gives a method to evaluate this.

Comment: This is well known [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos^n(t)=\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)$$

Let:

$\frac{\pi}{2}-t=x$,

$t=0 \implies x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$t=\frac{\pi}{2} \implies x=0$

$\mathrm{d}t=-\mathrm{d}x$

$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n(t)~\mathrm{d}t=-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin^n(x)\mathrm{d}x=-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \sin (x)(1-\cos^2x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Now expand $(1-\cos^2x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

You get a polynomial of form $au'u^k$, where $u'=\sin(x)$ and $u^k=\cos^k$ , which is integrable.

Answer (score 4):

Use integration by parts on
$$I(n)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}(t)dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)\cos^{n-1}(t)dt$$
then use the pythagorean identity on $\sin^2(t)$. You should end up with
$$I(n)=\frac{n-1}{n}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n-2}(t)dt=\frac{n-1}{n}I(n-2)$$

Comment: Thank you, In this way I will solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my teacher gave us what is given below, without proof.  If only this satisfies you, well and good, but if not, I'm gonna have to ask fellow members to help.[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is a reasonable answer for me.

Comment: I hope you understood the $1 or 2$ at the end of every bracketed term?

Comment: I know, it's okay.