# Integration of $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a(x)\cos^b(x).dx$ where $a<b-1/2$ and both $a$ and $b$ are even numbers.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**My approach:**
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a(x)\cos^b(x).dx$$
$$I = \frac12\int_0^{\pi/2} 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\ \sin^{a-1}(x)\cos^{b-1}(x).dx$$
$$I = \frac12\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2x)\ \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2a)}{2}}\bigg )^{a-1}\ \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2a)}{2}}\bigg )^{b-1}dx$$
$$I = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2x)\ \bigg(\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}\bigg )^{a-1}\ \bigg(\sqrt{1+\cos(2x)}\bigg )^{b-1}dx$$
Substitute $\cos(2x) = t$,
$$I = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}\int_0^{1} \bigg(\sqrt{1-t}\bigg )^{a-1}\ \bigg(\sqrt{1+t}\bigg )^{b-1}dx$$
$$I = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}\int_0^{1} (1-t)^\frac{a-1}{2}\ (1+t)^\frac{b-1}{2}dx$$

How should I proceed from here?

**Note**: The integral is actually the intermediate step of a question where I was asked to calculate the expectation of a random variable. So I need final expression in nice condensed form.

Comment: The original integral is just one of the definitions of the Beta function.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This made it really easy.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663567/571692) may help.